# incorrect maximum y value on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The y-values for my plot are incorrect.

```
data <- read.xlsx('filename')
data <- melt(data)
data$dvmph <- as.numeric(as.character(data$dvmph))

ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y = dvmph, 
                 fill=value)) + geom_col() + coord_polar() + labs(x="PDOF", y="dvmph") + scale_fill_gradient(low='khaki',high='red')
```

[image]

As you can see, the plot has a maximum dvmph of 500-- but the actual has a maximum dvmph of 49. Here's a sample of the data:

```
> data
   dvmph variable     value
1      1       X0      0.00
2      3       X0   2486.60
3      5       X0 100519.29
4      7       X0 471515.00
5      9       X0 973180.19
6     11       X0 758789.62
7     13       X0 500884.34
8     15       X0 441252.43
9     17       X0 228094.07
10    19       X0 358144.00
11    21       X0 173614.35
12    23       X0  73395.79
13    25       X0  79245.32
14    27       X0  59789.64
15    29       X0  35539.05
...
814    17     X350 116754.15
815    19     X350 173989.62
816    21     X350  76056.33
817    23     X350  32374.60
818    25     X350  26640.38
819    27     X350  34852.71
820    29     X350  11826.09
821    31     X350   7499.55
822    33     X350   4713.12
823    35     X350   4981.18
824    37     X350   5845.43
825    39     X350   2250.77
826    41     X350   2111.73
827    43     X350   1179.72
828    49     X350   5936.01

> max(data$dvmph)
[1] 49
```

I'm not quite sure what's causing this. I think it's something to do with `geom_col()`, because when I use `geom_tile()`, the plot looks correct (i.e. the y-axis ends at 50). But I can't use `geom_tile()` for aesthetic reasons (there's a gap in my data that is much more apparent when using `geom_tile()` than `geom_col()`).

Comment: `geom_col` has `position = "stack"` by default, that might be it

Comment: I tried changing to `position="dodge"` which [gave me this](http://imgur.com/kTGYus2.png). It mangled the colors, though I'm not sure how. And changing to `position="fill"` jkept the correct colors but made the y-values into proportions (.25, .5, etc.), which is not what I want...

Comment: position_identity?

Comment: Do you mean geom_col(position=position_identity())? I tried that and the plot looks the same as the one in my previous comment. Otherwise I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Yes, but that was just a guess. You should provide reproducible data

Comment: Apologies. Here you go. http://www.filedropper.com/data_49 You can also find it at http://pastebin.com/raw/nk2e8hLx.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y = dvmph, 
                 fill=value)) + geom_col(position="identity") + coord_polar() + labs(x="PDOF", y="dvmph") + scale_fill_gradient(low='khaki',high='red')
```

gives me the expected scale

[image]

I'm guessing you're using an old version of some package with a bug, try reinstalling/updating ggplot2 and its dependencies, and/or R, and make sure to run a vanilla R session.